# JQuery UI dialog form elements not being submitted with a form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dialog div within my form being submitted. The div is populated by check boxes dynamically with JavaScript. When I click the link to open the dialog, select a few check boxes, close, submit, my PHP process page is not registering the selected check boxes as POST items.

So, I believe that because the check boxes are dynamically generated after the page loads, they're not actually registered as elements in the form? Is this correct? Armed with this knowledge (or lack thereof), I have no idea how to circumvent this.

Any help would be much appreciated, I've searched around for help to no avail.

HTML:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">

        <div id="dialog" style="font-size:14px;">
            <div id="states_container">
                <div style="width:33%; float:left;" id="col1">

                </div>

                <div style="width:33%; float: left;" id="col2">

                </div>

                <div style="width:33%; float: left;" id="col3">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

submit.js (yes I know this is shitty code but I'm going to refactor):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
    });

    var states1 = {
        AL: "Alabama", 
        AK: "Alaska", 
        AZ: "Arizona", 
        AR: "Arkansas", 
        CA: "California", 
        CO: "Colorado", 
        CT: "Connecticut", 
        DE: "Delaware", 
        DC: "District Of Columbia", 
        FL: "Florida", 
        GA: "Georgia", 
        HI: "Hawaii", 
        ID: "Idaho", 
        IL: "Illinois", 
        IN: "Indiana", 
        IA: "Iowa",
        KS: "Kansas"
    };

    var states2 = {

        KY: "Kentucky", 
        LA: "Louisiana", 
        ME: "Maine", 
        MD: "Maryland", 
        MA: "Massachusetts", 
        MI: "Michigan", 
        MN: "Minnesota", 
        MS: "Mississippi", 
        MO: "Missouri", 
        MT: "Montana",
        NE: "Nebraska",
        NV: "Nevada",
        NH: "New Hampshire",
        NJ: "New Jersey",
        NM: "New Mexico",
        NY: "New York",
        NC: "North Carolina"
    };

    var states3 = {
        ND: "North Dakota",
        OH: "Ohio", 
        OK: "Oklahoma", 
        OR: "Oregon", 
        PA: "Pennsylvania", 
        RI: "Rhode Island", 
        SC: "South Carolina", 
        SD: "South Dakota",
        TN: "Tennessee", 
        TX: "Texas", 
        UT: "Utah", 
        VT: "Vermont", 
        VA: "Virginia", 
        WA: "Washington", 
        WV: "West Virginia", 
        WI: "Wisconsin", 
        WY: "Wyoming"
    };



    $.each(states1, function(key, value) {
        $('#col1').append(
            '<label for="' + value + '"><input type="checkbox" name="'+value+'" id="'+value+'">'+value+'</label><br/>'
        );
    });


    $.each(states2, function(key, value) {
        $('#col2').append(
            '<label for="' + value + '"><input type="checkbox" name="'+value+'" id="'+value+'">'+value+'</label><br/>'
        );
    });


    $.each(states3, function(key, value) {
        $('#col3').append(
            '<label for="' + value + '"><input type="checkbox" name="'+value+'" id="'+value+'">'+value+'</label><br/>'
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried nesting the form within (as a child of) the dialog div?

Comment: My guess is that jQueryUI detaches the dialog div and appends it to the body, so the form elements in the dialog are no longer children of your form.

Comment: j08691: Nope, unfortunately I have a massive amount of form elements before the dialog div. I took them out of the source I posted, for readability.

Comment: @TimAych - If memory serves me, I believe Jason P is correct. You can check this by using the browsers developer tools to inspect the DOM after the dialog has been created.

Comment: I suppose one solution would be to clone the form elements in the dialog and append them to the form before submit.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem exactly. Looking at the generated source, the location of the div is no longer in the form. Ah!

Answer (score 0):

Place this in form tag

```
<div id="dvDialog"></div>
```

And while opening form place this in jQuery before open command of dialog

```
$('#dialog').parent().appendTo('#dvDialog');
```

We need to do this because, when dialog is opened it is appended in DOM but not in Form tag, and as we know that when we are supposed to post data to any page we need controls or inputs inside in form tag, so this way we append dialog in div placed underneath form tag in DOM inside form tag.